# Minimum height of CustomListItem

Tags: bada

I have a customlist. I want to put in customlistitems of height 30 px. But when I do that they appear around 50 px. No matter what I do, the height of customlist item couldn't be brought down to 30 px.

Is it that the height of the customlist item is fixed to a certain minimum height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be the issue with prelaunch SDK. It suggests to use ListView instead, and use CustomItem to create items. Works fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

The [API](http://developer.bada.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.apireference.help/CompCustomListConstruct.html) tells that there are other issues when setting the height to a value smaller than 50. So it should be possible... But I am also not able to set a smaller height! Maybe thats a bug?

Comment: Havent been able to get a response on bada forum either. Maybe thats a bug only.